# Get the number of logical CPU cores sharing a cache (L1, L2, L3)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Below is some C++ code that detects the size of the L1, L2 and L3 CPU caches on Windows using [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GLPI)(PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION, PDWORD);

LPFN_GLPI glpi = (LPFN_GLPI) GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetLogicalProcessorInformation");

if (glpi)
{
    DWORD bytes = 0;
    glpi(0, &bytes);
    size_t size = bytes / sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION);
    vector<SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION> info(size);
    glpi(info.data(), &bytes);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (info[i].Relationship == RelationCache)
        {
            if (info[i].Cache.Level == 1)
              l1_cache_Size = info[i].Cache.Size;
            if (info[i].Cache.Level == 2)
              l2_cache_Size = info[i].Cache.Size;
            if (info[i].Cache.Level == 3)
              l3_cache_Size = info[i].Cache.Size;
        }
    }
}
```

As a next step I would like to get the number of logical CPU cores sharing a cache. On a x64 CPU with hyper-threading two logical CPU cores usually share an L2 cache and all logical CPU cores share the L3 cache.

After reading through MSDN I thought that `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` and [CACHE_RELATIONSHIP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405483(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GROUP_AFFINITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405500(v=vs.85).aspx) where the data structures I was looking for but after trying it out these data structures seem useless for my purpose.

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the number of logical CPU cores sharing a cache on Windows using C/C++? (Ideally without using `cpuid` directly)

---

**Solution:**

The number of logical CPU cores sharing a cache can be obtained using `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` and the [CACHE_RELATIONSHIP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405483(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GROUP_AFFINITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405500(v=vs.85).aspx) data structures. The `GROUP_AFFINITY.Mask` value contains one bit set for each CPU core that shares the current cache (`RelationCache`). As an example for most Intel CPUs with hyper-threading `GROUP_AFFINITY.Mask` will contain 2 bits set for the L2 cache and 8 bits set for the L3 cache for a CPU with 4 physical CPU cores and 8 logical CPU cores.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GLPI)(LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP,
    PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX, PDWORD);

int main()
{
    LPFN_GLPI glpi = (LPFN_GLPI) GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx");

    if (!glpi)
        return 1;

    DWORD bytes = 0;
    glpi(RelationAll, 0, &bytes);
    vector<char> buffer(bytes);
    SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX* info;

    if (!glpi(RelationAll, (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX*) &buffer[0], &bytes))
        return 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; i += info->Size)
    {
        info = (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX*) &buffer[i];

        if (info->Relationship == RelationCache &&
            (info->Cache.Type == CacheData ||
             info->Cache.Type == CacheUnified))
        {
            cout << "info->Cache.Level: " << (int) info->Cache.Level << endl;
            cout << "info->Cache.CacheSize: " << (int) info->Cache.CacheSize << endl;
            cout << "info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: " << info->Cache.GroupMask.Group << endl;
            cout << "info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: " << info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Caveats:**

I have found that when running Windows inside a virtual machine the code above was unable to correctly detect the number of CPU cores sharing the caches, e.g. on a VM with 2 virtual CPU cores the code above reports that each logical CPU core has a private L1, L2 and L3 cache.

Comment: but `CACHE_RELATIONSHIP` and containing all needed info. `number of logical CPU cores` ? number of bits set in `Cache->GroupMask.Mask`.

Answer (score 2):

> **@RbMm:** but CACHE_RELATIONSHIP contains all info needed. number of logical CPU cores = number of bits set in Cache->GroupMask.Mask

I have tested this on AppVeyor CI (even before posting to stackoverflow). Here is the output for an x64 CPU:

```
info->Cache.Level: 1
info->Cache.CacheSize: 32768
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 1

info->Cache.Level: 1
info->Cache.CacheSize: 32768
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 1

info->Cache.Level: 2
info->Cache.CacheSize: 262144
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 1

info->Cache.Level: 3
info->Cache.CacheSize: 31457280
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 1

info->Cache.Level: 1
info->Cache.CacheSize: 32768
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 2

info->Cache.Level: 1
info->Cache.CacheSize: 32768
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 2

info->Cache.Level: 2
info->Cache.CacheSize: 262144
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 2

info->Cache.Level: 3
info->Cache.CacheSize: 31457280
info->Cache.GroupMask.Group: 0
info->Cache.GroupMask.Mask: 2
```

Or:

```
| Cache Level |    Processor 1     |    Processor 2     |
|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| L1          |  32 KB Data        |  32 KB Data        |
|             |  32 KB Instruction |  32 KB Instruction |
|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| L2          | 256 KB Unified     | 256 KB Unified     |
|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| L3          |  30 MB Unified     |  30 MB Unified     |
```

According to the MSDN documentation:

> **GroupMask.Mask** - A bitmap that specifies the affinity for zero or more processors within the specified group.

Based on this documentation I was expecting a different `GroupMask.Mask` for the L3 cache, but the output above does not show this. To me the data in `GroupMask.Mask` makes no sense!

Here is a [link to the code](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve/blob/4a0591c5903f56fd0f69f777db6ee55d16a12787/src/primesieve/CpuInfo.cpp#L180) which produces that data above

Comment: look like you have 2 core and they not share L3 cache. why you think this wrong ? so only 1 core per cache in your case (what is your cpu ?). in my test (i5,i7) L3 cache shared for all cores, when L1 and L2 shared per physical core (2 threads)

Comment: @RbMm: My tests were run on a system with a recent Intel Xeon CPU (Appveyor CI). Personally I think that the mask for the L3 cache is wrong, I think the L3 cache is shared and that Windows (or a VM) cannot change the L3 CPU sharing. I don't know this for sure, but it is an educated guess.

Comment: hm, this can be very specific cpu depend, but in my test (i5,i7) - L3 cache have *Unified* type and share between all cores. L1 and L2 is per physical core (so shared per 2 logical core (hyper-threading)). but why you think that on same cpu can not be another result ? L3 not common

Comment: @RbMm: The CPU type I am using is: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz. According to online documentation this CPU has 30 MB L3 cache (correctly reported by our code) but the L3 cache is shared by all CPU cores (as correctly guessed by myself). I am guessing that this is a Windows (or VM) bug caused by running Windows in a VM. The L3 cache is definitely shared at a hardware level, I don't think it is possible to change the L3 cache sharing by the OS or the VM.

Comment: but here 12 core/24 threads - are you dump exactly for this cpu ? if say run my code for it - which will be output ?

Comment: @RbMm: Using your code the output is: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/kimwalisch/primesieve/build/1.0.517/job/kcafdnbo8nxscg3f#L866. The reason why our code is not showing the correct number of CPU cores (and also the erroneous GroupMask data) is because Appveyor CI is running many VMs with 2 virtual CPU cores on the Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680.

Comment: but if running in VM - windows not view (and can not) real physical processor. and can not give actual info for it. virtual machine have virtual processor - and here all ok. the `documentation` for physical processor not relevant here. you need test on physical comp (host) for get relevant result

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks a lot for your answers. I think the code works fine and I will use it. I can live the fact that the code does not properly work on VMs but I still think it is a bug. On Linux I have no issues to detect the number of logical CPU cores sharing a cache (and the real physical CPU) even on a VM!

Answer (score 0):

may be result depend from specific processor and windows version, but i test (win10) on 2 processors and got correct result:

i5 (2 core, 4 threads):

```
ProcessorPackage
    [G0 000000000000000F { #3, #2, #1, #0}]
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=8 Unified
Cache L3   300000 40 [G0 000000000000000F { #3, #2, #1, #0}] A=c Unified
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=8 Unified
NumaNode #0 [G0 000000000000000F { #3, #2, #1, #0}]
Group:1/1
    4/4 [000000000000000F { #3, #2, #1, #0}]
```

i7 (4 core, 8 threads):

```
ProcessorPackage
    [G0 00000000000000FF { #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1, #0}]
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 0000000000000003 { #1, #0}] A=4 Unified
Cache L3   800000 40 [G0 00000000000000FF { #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1, #0}] A=10 Unified
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 000000000000000C { #3, #2}] A=4 Unified
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 0000000000000030 { #5, #4}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000030 { #5, #4}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 0000000000000030 { #5, #4}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 0000000000000030 { #5, #4}] A=4 Unified
ProcessorCore HP=1 0
    [G0 00000000000000C0 { #7, #6}]
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 00000000000000C0 { #7, #6}] A=8 Data
Cache L1     8000 40 [G0 00000000000000C0 { #7, #6}] A=8 Instruction
Cache L2    40000 40 [G0 00000000000000C0 { #7, #6}] A=4 Unified
NumaNode #0 [G0 00000000000000FF { #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1, #0}]
Group:1/1
    8/8 [00000000000000FF { #7, #6, #5, #4, #3, #2, #1, #0}]
```

code:

```
void FormatMask(KAFFINITY Mask, PSTR sz)
{
    sz += sprintf(sz, "%p {", (PVOID)Mask);

    ULONG i = sizeof(KAFFINITY) * 8;
    do
    {
        if (_bittest((PLONG)&Mask, --i))
        {
            sz += sprintf(sz, " #%u,", i);
        }
    } while (i);

    *--sz = '}';
}

void DumpCpuInfo()
{
    static PCSTR szCacheType[] = {
        "Unified",
        "Instruction",
        "Data",
        "Trace"
    };

    char szMask[64 * 5 + 19];
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x400;
    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    union {
        PVOID Buffer;
        PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX plpi;
    };

    do
    {
        if (cb < rcb) rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(Buffer = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

        if (GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(::RelationAll, plpi, &rcb))
        {
            DWORD Size;
            do
            {
                Size = plpi->Size;

                union {
                    PPROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP Processor;
                    PNUMA_NODE_RELATIONSHIP NumaNode;
                    PCACHE_RELATIONSHIP     Cache;
                    PGROUP_RELATIONSHIP     Group;
                    PVOID pv;
                };

                pv = &plpi->Processor;

                switch (plpi->Relationship)
                {
                case RelationProcessorPackage:
                    DbgPrint("ProcessorPackage\n");
                    goto __0;
                case RelationProcessorCore:
                    DbgPrint("ProcessorCore HP=%x %x\n",
                        Processor->Flags & LTP_PC_SMT ? 1 : 0, Processor->EfficiencyClass);
__0:
                    if (WORD GroupCount = Processor->GroupCount)
                    {
                        PGROUP_AFFINITY GroupMask = Processor->GroupMask;
                        do
                        {
                            FormatMask(GroupMask->Mask, szMask);
                            DbgPrint("\t[G%u %s]\n", GroupMask->Group, szMask);
                        } while (GroupMask++, --GroupCount);
                    }
                    break;

                case RelationNumaNode:
                    FormatMask(NumaNode->GroupMask.Mask, szMask);
                    DbgPrint("NumaNode #%u [G%u %s]\n",
                        NumaNode->NodeNumber, NumaNode->GroupMask.Group, szMask);
                    break;

                case RelationGroup:
                    DbgPrint("Group:%u/%u\n", Group->ActiveGroupCount, Group->MaximumGroupCount);
                    if (WORD ActiveGroupCount = Group->ActiveGroupCount)
                    {
                        PPROCESSOR_GROUP_INFO GroupInfo = Group->GroupInfo;
                        do
                        {
                            FormatMask(GroupInfo->ActiveProcessorMask, szMask);
                            DbgPrint("\t%u/%u [%s]\n",
                                GroupInfo->ActiveProcessorCount,
                                GroupInfo->MaximumProcessorCount, szMask);
                        } while (GroupInfo, --ActiveGroupCount);
                    }
                    break;

                case RelationCache:
                    FormatMask(Cache->GroupMask.Mask, szMask);
                    DbgPrint("Cache L%u %8x %2x [G%u %s] A=%x %s\n",
                        Cache->Level,
                        Cache->CacheSize, Cache->LineSize,
                        Cache->GroupMask.Group, szMask,
                        Cache->Associativity,
                        szCacheType[Cache->Type % RTL_NUMBER_OF(szCacheType)]
                    );
                    break;
                }
                Buffer = RtlOffsetToPointer(plpi, Size);
            } while (rcb -= Size);
            break;
        }
    } while (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the code! I will report back once I get it working on my system...

Comment: @Linoliumz - of course you can replace `DbgPrint` to another print method, and say [`RtlOffsetToPointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553160(v=vs.85).aspx) macro to another equal or at all allocate buffer from heap, not from stack (runtime checks must be off for this). but this not change main - parse and print `SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX` structs. in your case look like processor with 2 core, 2 threads

Comment: if anyone is interested I have this working in c# using PInvoke

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative solution from boost library.

```
// number of logical cores
auto logical = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();

// number of physical cores
auto physical = boost::thread::physical_concurrency();
```

But cache is not considered.